# Do noindex,follow pages pass pagerank / link juice?

Tags: pagerank, noindex, dofollow

Assuming one marks a page as 'noindex,follow', is PageRank / link juice passed to other pages nevertheless?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.

> Eric Enge: Can a NoIndex page accumulate PageRank?
>
> Matt Cutts: A NoIndex page can accumulate PageRank, because the links
>   are still followed outwards from a NoIndex page.
>
> Eric Enge: So, it can accumulate and pass PageRank.
>
> Matt Cutts: Right, and it will still accumulate PageRank, but it won't
>   be showing in our Index. So, I wouldn't make a NoIndex page that
>   itself is a dead end. You can make a NoIndex page that has links to
>   lots of other pages.

http://www.stonetemple.com/articles/interview-matt-cutts.shtml

Comment: @JVerstry the really important part to read here is `published: October 2007`. You can run your own tests by checking your noindex pages for a pagerank if it has NA your see that things have changed.

Comment: Yes, it is 7 years old. Do you have something official & more up to date which refutes that ? This is not about Google Toolbar Pagerank, it is about internal pagerank, which still matters very much. (No point testing Toolbar page rank, it is defunk and hardly updated)

Comment: You are confusing toolbar pagerank with internal page rank.

Comment: toolbar pagerank reads internal page rank, which has been updated twice in the last two years.

Comment: Your see that non-indexed pages receive a page rank of NA... This is only when they update their toolbar.

Comment: Please, toolbar pagerank is not internal page rank. Last time toolbar values where exported was last year and they gave a broad snapshot of one given day in history.

Comment: @JVerstry - just to clarify, you can see much the same being said here 2012 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bB6IJHxhlRQ#t=34m0s (Toolbar page rank is an indicator of very little.)

Comment: Normally people associate pagerank that reported by the toolbar, I have never heard of an internal invisible page rank, I normally associate that with everyday ranking algorithms or domain authority, which is not related to Google's dinosaurs pagerank algorithm. The question should  be changed to does linking on pages that are not indexed help rankings? as it's clearly not whats being asked here.

Comment: This is getting dumb now. Of course there is an internal page rank, it is that page rank which is exported to the tool bar page rank sporadically, whilst internally it is updated consistently. Page rank is loosely a calculation of links (quantity and quality) and links are still a ranking factor. The page rank toolbar is sliding out of existence due to no longer being supported/default on many major browsers, I cannot imagine that anyone other than pure novice searchers would assign any weight to the values reported in the toolbar ( or indeed still have the page rank toolbar installed!)

Comment: PageRank 'WAS' used by Google to determine the flow of juice and authority on a page from a scale from 0 - 10... The same data used was pushed several times a year to the toolbar... Now Google nowadays doesn't update this data, but the old data reported by Googles Toolbar is  valid to the point of the last update. There's no difference between Google's pagerank and that of the toolbar pagerank other than the data used is not realtime. It should be easy to disprove my theory by looking up the millions of 'still live' data on old urls and domains.

Comment: Your theory has been disproved already by Google sources that PR/link calculations are processed on a noindex page.PR toolbar is not relevant here, this is not about the toolbar values. Seems like you have made your assumptions on noindex pgs being n/a.its a fact that Google collects values for noindex pgs, but ? if these values are sent to the toolbar, or if sent - are displayed in the toolbar. The toolbar is a different issue. tbh I am not really interested in a long term discussion of PR, I simply answered the question "noindex,follow pages pass pagerank / link juice?"  With a Yes.

Comment: Matt's statement is still correct. In a similar vein, pages that are disallowed from crawling in the robots.txt can also collect PageRank. These are essentially technical aspects of Google's algorithms, and not something you'd need to optimize for with most (probably all) real websites (I haven't seen any sites where either of these cases was causing a noticable problem).

Answer (score 3):

Google recently (December 2017) said that `noindex,follow` pages end up not not passing link juice.

Initially link juice will get passed, but eventually the links on the `noindex` page will be ignored.  Long term, `noindex,follow` is equivelent to `noindex,nofollow`.  See:  [Google: Long Term Noindex Will Lead To Nofollow Also](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-long-term-noindex-follow-24990.html)