# "NOINDEX, FOLLOW" turns into NOFOLLOW eventually. Solution is Canonical?

Tags: seo, canonical-url, noindex, nofollow, link-juice

I have recently discovered that Google treats "noindex,follow" pages as "noindex,nofollow" eventually -> https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/115879

I have a website with hotel listings. I provide other websites data in embedded iframes, such as "X City Hotels". People add these iframe to their sidebars so I thought I was receiving link juice from those iframes. The structure of the pages is like this:

*website.com/city/london/hotels* - This page has all the info on it, plus header, footer, sidebars sections and etc. It's a regular webpage with lots of other info other than the specific "london hotels listings" data.
*website.com/iframe?city=london* : This page only has the data, in a simple responsive table. Nothing else.

I use the robots tag with "noindex,follow", so that there won't be duplicate results on the Google search results. But I also use *follow* on the robots tag (or in other words i dont add *nofollow*), so that when someone embeds the iframe to their site, it passes link juice (the iframe listings are not only plain data, they are also linked to my inner pages)

Having learned about this "noindex turning into nofollow eventually", what should I do? Should I remove the "noindex" from the iframe page and instead add a canonical tag to my main page (website.com/city/london/hotels)?

The pages aren't exactly the same. Iframe page is very simple. Would Google assume it's just duplicate content and ignore it? Or stop visiting the iframe (and stop passing the link juice as well) once the googlebot sees the canonical tag?

How should I go about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!

Comment: *Should I remove the "noindex" from the iframe page and instead add a canonical tag to my main page (website.com/city/london/hotels)?* Bingo! You got it.